# ASP.NET MVC - Post data to Facebook

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post data to facebook after fetching access token using graph api in asp.net mvc5 but losing my data to post after getting access token.

Here is what I'm doing in my View

```
 <a href='@Url.Action("PostFacebook", "SocialMedia")/?videoId=@Model.VideoSourceId'>
     <img src='@Url.Content("~/Assests/layout/images/social/share-facebook.png")' alt="Share on Facebook!" style="height:28px" />
 </a>
```

Here is what I've on my PostFacebook action of SocialMedia controller.

```
 public void PostFacebook(int? videoId)
 {
     string redirectUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
     if (Request["code"] == null)
     {
        string url = string.Format(
        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
        FbClientId, redirectUrl, scope);
        Response.Redirect(url);
     }
     else
     {
         redirectUrl = string.Format("{0}?code={1}", redirectUrl, Request["code"]);
         string accessToken = GetAccessToken(redirectUrl);
         FacebookClient facebook = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

         //get data about video here and set parameters
         //MY PROBLEM LIES HERE, VideoId is null always so i can't get the values about my post from my database.
         facebook.Post("/me/feed", parameters);
     }
 }
```

I understand why it is null on my second call because when we redirect to oauth/authorize?.. we get out of that method and lose all of the information and when facebook returns us the code to our redirect_url we can't get the VideoId back.

My configured redirect_url is SocialMedia/PostFacebook/

I'm confused in how to send videoId to Facebook oauth/authorize endpoint and get it back with the CODE or if its even possible? If not, what techniques do I have to persist my parameters in such scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it to work by changing the followings.

1) My redirect_uri was `http://localhost:53923/SocialMedia/Facebook/`
and i changed it to `http://localhost:53923/SocialMedia/Facebook/?videoId` which is a strange thing for me. Facebook plugs in the videoId by itself now.

2) Second i just updated my redirect uri in the code from

`string redirectUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);` 
to

`string redirectUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`.

It worked!